# resharper and attribute formatting

Tags: resharper

When R# formats a method with multiple attributes in a single line (see below) it puts in an extra line. The only C# option I see for attributes and methods is to place it on the same line, which isn't what I want.

Has anyone seen this one before? Got a fix?

Cheers,
Berryl

## the way it should be

```
[TestCase(101, 99, 200), TestCase(101, -99, 2)]
public void Plus_WithWholeAmounts(decimal lhs, decimal rhs, decimal result)
{
    // doStuff
}
```

## after R# reformats (unwanted line after attributes)

```
[TestCase(101, 99, 200), TestCase(101, -99, 2)]

public void Plus_WithWholeAmounts(decimal lhs, decimal rhs, decimal result)
{
    // doStuff
}
```

Comment: Tried submitting it to the JetBrains' tracker? Seems like a bug.

Comment: @petrk. I don't have the link for that and a quick search brings up links for some bug tracking product they are pushing to sell. I would think with all their Jet Brains and aggressive release schedules they could at least assign someone to watch SO for issues.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RSRP

Comment: Have you checked any of the settings in Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Blank Lines

Comment: @ChrisMissal. I did try that one, no dice.

Comment: @petrk. Thanks for the link. You had the right answer (it's a BUG), so please put it in an answer format so I can credit you and close this out. Cheers